# Confused about some norms with a variety of subscripts

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I read some books and papers and I am confused about some norms with a variety of subscripts that are not uniform. I mean, some of the subscripts are sets while others are spaces.

In particular, can you help me to understand the specific definitions of the following norms I see in the books and papers?

\begin{align}
&\|x\|_\Sigma \\
&\|x\|_{L^\infty(\Sigma)} \\
&\|x\|_{L^p(\Sigma)} \\
&\|x\|_{W_\infty^2(\Sigma)} \\
&\|x\|_{H^1(\Sigma)} \\
&\|x\|_{H^2 \;\text{without}\; (\Sigma)} 
\end{align}

where $x$ may be a function defined on $\Omega \supset \Sigma$.

In addition, I also see some subscripts are numbers or $\infty$, such as $\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_\infty$. In these cases I think $x$ must be a sequence rather than a function, and they are abbreviations for $\|x\|_{l_2}$ and $\|x\|_{l_\infty}$?

Comment: Can you provide us with some of the books and papers where you've seen such notations? It might help.

Comment: As for one of the papers, you may find it via the following two links: 

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140982696

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3043 (free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked the paper so far. The norms are defined as above:
For $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $v:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$ we have

$||v||_{\Sigma}=\left(\int_{\Sigma}v(t)^2dt\right)^{1/2}$, the "square mean value".

For $1\leq p < \infty$ we have

$||v||_{L^p(\Sigma)}=\left(\int_{\Sigma}|v(t)|^p dt\right)^{1/p}$, the $L^p$ norm on $\Sigma$,

for the case $p=\infty$ and so for the $L^{\infty}$-norm i refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space and the construction of the essential supremum.

Then for $s\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $1\leq p\leq \infty$ we have

$||v||_{W^s_p(\Sigma)}=\sum_{i=1}^{s}||\partial_t^{i}v||_{L^p(\Sigma)},$   the Sobolev norm,

for a first introduction see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space.

If we choose $p=2$ in the Sobolev setting we use for shorten the notion

$W^s_2(\Sigma)=H^s(\Sigma)$

and so we have

$||v||_{H^1(\Sigma)}=||v||_{W^1_2(\Sigma)}, \quad ||v||_{H^2(\Sigma)}=||v||_{W^2_2(\Sigma)}.$

Comment: Regarding the $L^\infty$-norm, is $\|v\|_{L^\infty(\Sigma)} := \inf\{C \ge 0: |v(x)| \le C \text{ for a.e.} x \in \Sigma \}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: Can you declare my answer as a right one?